# How to get full output of python program?

Tags: python, logging, output

How can I redirect absolutely full output of python program, that is seen in command line to file? Also the things from logging should be there. When I try to redirect the program output I only get stuff from print statements, not from logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a handler to specifically log to the file.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/var/tmp/myapp.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```